# scrolling two divs with docking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two skinny divs next to each other. Both are too tall to fit within a window but one is significantly taller then the second one.

In the beginngin they have alligned top edges. When I start scrolling down nothing remarkable should happen until the bottom of the shorter div touches the bottom of they viwing area.

In this moment this shorter div must freeze and as I keep scrolling down it should always be docked to the bottom of the viewing area.

At this moment, if I start scrolling up the shorter div sgould undock and keep scrolling until its upper edge touches the upper border of the viewing port.

As a summary: the longest div should be scrollable naturally but the shorter div should never disappear from view and this is accomplished by docking it to the lower or upper edge of the window.

Here is a semi working solution that I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/Laod7wLr/

```
    <div class="parent">
    <div id="col1"> 
        Header
        <div class="content"> </div>
        Footer
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        Header
        <div class="content"> </div>
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
}

#col1, #col2{
    width:350px;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
#col1{
    background:grey;

}
#col2{
    background:darkgrey;
    right:0;
}

#col1 .content{
    height:2000px;
}

#col2 .content{
    height:1600px;
}
```

My idea was to detect the shortest div touches one of the edgest of the viewing area and then adjust its position to FIXED. When a croll direction changed I bring it back to ABSOLUTE

I succesfully detect OnScrollUp/Down events and make proper checks but when I change positions of the element form FIXED to ABSOLUTE I get a jumpy behavior.

I start wondering if this approach with juggling FIXED/ABSOLUTE is the a correct one. Maybe there is a plug in that would accomplish this behavior.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By 'jumpy behavior' you mean when it jumps to the right 8px when it's `fixed` and back to the left 8px when it's `absolute` again?

Comment: No, well that one too, but when I adjust from fixed to absolute it also moves the shorter div way up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Laod7wLr/14/

Check out the JSFiddle that I am providing.

I changed a css element because the math was a little off causing a very weird instance. This should be the default of what you do any way in your css. I did not see it in the JS you provided.

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I only use 1 scroll event to check for everything and I'm not breaking up everything into functions even though it is possible to do so.

It is hard to explain exactly each step, but this works very well for what you're asking for.

Let me know if you have more questions on the matter.

Comment: This sadly will only work when the second div is the shortest... It can be modified to specify class based detection if we wanted it to, but I'm not exactly sure how I would move forward with that right away. Let us just assume that `#col1` is always taller.

Comment: Everything is clear from your code. This is a simple and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jump from fixed to absolute when scrolling up only when scroll to top distance is less than height of your smaller div. Otherwise let it remain fixed.

You can get the scroll distance from window top via `$(window).scrollTop()`.